# What does QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False do?

Tags: excel, vba

What does the statement

```
Selection.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

do in excel macro?  Does it disable background refresh for the selected table?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.querytable.backgroundquery

Comment: ok so I am correct I guess?..

Comment: If the `Selection` has a `QueryTable`...